# Extracting data in Excel and transposing/formatting it in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new here and have been referred to this site by someone who thinks its the best site for programmers. I also think it is!!

I am new to VBA and Excel macros.
I want to do the following things with a spreadsheet having 13 columns and 1000 rows.

1. Determine the unique items in Columns A to J
2. Move the unique items to a new sheet
3. Transpose the data on the new sheet from columns to rows
4. Space the unique items (the rows would be determined by the data to be fixed beneath which varies)
5. Sort the raw data based on unique items from columns B through J
6. and populate the new sheet created earlier by using the unique items and data just after the column with the unique item
7. Create a subtotal for each populated data

Here is a format below:

```
      A     B     C     D      E       F     G       ... L   M
    1 Mike  mazer Male  White  London  SE    Barman  ... 36  4.52
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes that can be done with Excel Macros recording common Excel commands. I'd suggest getting familiar with the Macro recorder, and then heading over to superuser.com to learn any Excel commands that you might need to record.

steps 1-2 could be done with the following:

https://superuser.com/questions/49614/excel-get-distinct-values-in-column

I've personally recorded a lot of excel commands just to see what VB code it would spit out. its a good way to learn VB

it looks like you'd need to "pivot" the data for step 3 (read up on excel pivot tables)

for 7, look into the Data>SubTotal command. It has a few different ways to configure it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch KevinDeus. I have achieved steps 1 and 2. Any suggestions on steps 4 and 5?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a lot of parts. It might be easiest if you broke up those parts and just asked about the things giving you difficulty.

Although, If you can already handle this problem manually, I would suggest just using excel to record a macro (you can find this function on the Visual Basic toolbar) of you running through all the steps and then opening the macro in the vba editor to tweak the code later.

Of course if you get stuck on any of the intermediate steps, you can always ask another question. People here are glad to help. Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thanks Shaka. I have solved 1,2 and hopefully 3. Do you have any clue on 4-6? many thanks

Comment: My initial thought is that you might be able to get somewhere by playing with the AutoFilter (located under Filter in the Data menu). I don't quite understand what you're trying to do but the AutoFilter is a very powerful tool for sorting through data. And of course, you can always ask another question now that you've made some progress on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose() function to flip the values.

Example: For an entire row,

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose("A1":"A1".End(xlToLeft))
```

Comment: Thanks Lance. Please can you give me the arguement in the Transpose property. I am trying to select all the data in the newsheet which contains the transposed data and have it all tranposed starting from A(1,1) down the row. many thanks

Comment: I edited in a quick example based on one row, your parameter is just the range you want to transpose, and of course you want to assign it to an range of the correct reverse dimensions.  you can use xldown for the column, there are many ways to grab ranges in excel.